# WCF error "has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints"

Tags: c#, wcf

I am attempting to create a basic WCF application but I am getting an error when I run it:

This is the Service:

```
namespace WcfTranslationLibrary
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITranslationService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Translate(string value);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
}
```

This is my class:

```
namespace WcfTranslationLibrary
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class PigLatinTranslator : ITranslationService
    {
        public string Translate(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfTranslationLibrary.PigLatinTranslator">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfTranslationLibrary.ITranslationService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfTranslationLibrary/PigLatinTranslator/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

And this is the console app i use:

```
namespace ServiceHostConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PigLatinTranslator));
            myHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Translator running...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            myHost.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/hello"); <--url

            // Create the ServiceHost.
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseAddress)) <-- url
            {
                // Enable metadata publishing.  
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior(); <-- metadata
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
                // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
                // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
                // by the service.
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think you missed some settings, at least url, take a look into sample provided by [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)